# Display hidden icons on taskbar

Tags: windows-7, icons

How to make windows to always show hidden icons on taskbar in Windows 7 (Profesional Service Pack 1,  saying just in case that it isnt same on other versions)

[image]

So I dont have to click to see what is running.

Comment: And if you want **one** of the icons to stay visible you can also drag it down to the clock area and it will stay visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Click the `Customize...` button in the tray menu.

[image]

2. Click `Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar.`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

you go to customize, at the bottom it says show all icons.

[image]